# How to install only MySQL client in Windows 10?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL client (and nothing else) on *Windows* (not Linux).

I have a AWS EC2 instance along with MySQL RDS, My intention is to execute scripts from EC2 instance by connecting to the RDS server, So I don't want to install a complete MySQL server (huge) or MySQL Workbench (I will be using .bat file), so I just want to connect with the MySQL client and execute scripts on the remote server!

I tried installing only the client from the MySQL installer, but there is no option at all to choose server-only or client-only. I remember such an option was there before in the installer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think u missed , I am asking for WINDOWS

Comment: It helps to mention these things clearly in your question.

Answer (score 2):

While installing MySQL 5.7.20.0 Community Edition, you will be asked what type of installation you want and you can choose **Client only**:

[image]